# Variables marked as const using structured bindings are not const

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, structured-bindings

I have been writing a set of classes to allow for a simple python-like `zip`-function. The following snippet works (almost) just as expected. However, the two variables `a` and `b` are not `const`.

```
std::vector<double> v1{0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
std::vector<int> v2{0, 1, 2};

for (auto const& [a, b] : zip(v1, v2))
{
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << std::endl;
    a = 3; // I expected this to give a compiler error, but it does not
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << std::endl;
}
```

I have been using gcc 7.3.0.
Here is the MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <class ... Ts>
class zip_iterator
{
    using value_iterator_type = std::tuple<decltype( std::begin(std::declval<Ts>()))...>;
    using value_type          = std::tuple<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Ts>()))...>;
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;

    value_iterator_type i;

    template <std::size_t ... I>
    value_type dereference(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return value_type{*std::get<I>(i) ...};
    }

public:
    zip_iterator(value_iterator_type it) : i(it) {}

    value_type operator*()
    {
        return dereference(Indices{});
    }
};

template <class ... Ts>
class zipper
{
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;

    std::tuple<Ts& ...> values;

    template <std::size_t ... I>
    zip_iterator<Ts& ...> beginner(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::begin(std::get<I>(values)) ...);
    }

public:
    zipper(Ts& ... args) : values{args...} {}

    zip_iterator<Ts& ...> begin()
    {
        return beginner(Indices{});
    }
};

template <class ... Ts>
zipper<Ts& ...> zip(Ts& ... args)
{
    return {args...};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v{1};
    auto const& [a] = *zip(v).begin();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    a = 2; // I expected this to give a compiler error, but it does not
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Same on VC++.  .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a tuple of a reference, which means that the reference itself will be `const` qualified (which is ill-formed but in this context [ignored](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#dcl.ref-1.sentence-3)), not the value referenced by it.

```
int a = 7;
std::tuple<int&> tuple = a;
const auto&[aa] = tuple;
aa = 9; // ok
```

If you look how `std::get` is defined, you'll see that it returns `const std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<int&>>&` for the structured binding above. As the first tuple element is a reference, the `const&` has no effect, and thus you can modify the return value.

Really, it's same thing if you have a class pointer/reference member that you can modify in a `const` qualified member function (the value pointed/referenced that is).

Comment: Can the reference be mutable?

Comment: @W.F. What do you mean, a non-const ref is mutable.

Comment: I mean that you can't really mutate a reference as you can't overwrite the referenced object. Or can you?

Comment: @W.F. No, that's not possible. But why does that apply?

Comment: I am not following your explanation at all. What do you mean by `, which means that the reference itself will be const qualified, not the value referenced by it.`? The reference is just another name for the object. Any operation on it is an operation on the object it is bound to. I can't understand the meaning of 'reference itself'.

Comment: @SergeyA I mean this `int& const`, the reference is const

Comment: I mean if the reference cannot be mutated how can it be const...?

Comment: @SergeyA I think he means that, even though references can't be const qualified like pointers can, the syntax is consistent with pointers such that the `const&` reference of the structured binding falls on the reference **as if** it would should it be allowed in normal code.

Comment: @W.F. exactly, that's why const is ignored http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#dcl.ref-1.sentence-3

Comment: @Rakete1111 with your last reference to Standard answer now becomes much clearer. Your last sentence still is unclear, though. If you think it is valid, I believe, an example would be in order.

Comment: @SergeyA is that better?

Comment: Awkward it is but it seems legit... Nice finding!

Comment: When you say  "it's same thing if you have a class pointer/reference member that you can modify in a const qualified member function", if I try to change a member pointer in a const qualified member function it says error, pointer must be a modifiable value.

Comment: @Zebrafish See what I wrote in the parens at the end. I you have a better idea how to word this, please edit.

Comment: @Zebrafish There is no reason for `int& const` to be disallowed other than the fact that it is redundant. So we can't write it like that. But that is where the syntax places it with the structured binding. Same as if you had `std::tuple<int*>`

Comment: So how to provide a structured binding with an identifier which won't be able to modify the underlying  *non-const* reference's lvalue?

Comment: @bloody, in C++23, `for (auto [a, b] : std::views::zip(v1, v2) | std::views::as_const)` makes `a` and `b` `const double&` and `const int&` respectively.